# Attribute compute not working in ORB from openCV for python

Tags: python, opencv, orb

I start learning Python (2.7) and I try to work on computer vision (with module openCv "cv2"). I use OpenCV version2.4.

I'm currently trying to run an example from [this tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_orb/py_orb.html) which is on ORB (orb oriented fast and rotated brief) which would help me to track objects on a video.

The problem is that I got an error when I run the example (I just change the image loading in order to make this example reproducible) :

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#create image
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
cv2.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)

# Initiate STAR detector
orb = cv2.ORB()

# find the keypoints with ORB
kp = orb.detect(img,None)

# compute the descriptors with ORB
kp, des = orb.compute(img, kp)

# draw only keypoints location,not size and orientation
img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img,kp,color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
plt.imshow(img2),plt.show()
```

I then have the following message error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f294d6a53bcc> in <module>()
     12 print(kp)
     13 # compute the descriptors with ORB
---> 14 kp, des = orb.compute(img, kp)
     15 
     16 # draw only keypoints location,not size and orientation

AttributeError: 'cv2.ORB' object has no attribute 'compute'
```

I don't understand why this attribute doesn't exist for this object. Does my script suppress it ?

Any help is very welcome.

Thanks a lot.
Edwin

Answer (score 0):

I also just started to learn OpenCV, in my case also for python.
My Version is Win7 64bit, python 2.7.8, OpenCV 2.4.10.

the error message was : AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ORB'

My Solution was to install the Unofficial Binaries from here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv